# Magento и блоки

Tags: magento

Подскажите пожалуйста, в какие блоки можно добавлять свои блоки через layout update ?
Например, я заметил что без проблем добавляеся в

```
<block type="core/text_list"
```

А вот, во всякие там

```
<block type="checkout/cart"
```

не хочет, или я что то не правильно делаю или всё таки вставлять блоки через layout update можно не во все типы ? Буду очень признателен если подкинете ссылочку где описан этот вопрос (можно и на английском) а то что то нагуглить ничего толком не могу :(

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем, предположение оказалось частично правильным.

Добавлять блоки посредством `layout\-update` можно только в те блоки где есть что-то вроде:

```
foreach ($this->getSortedChildren() as $name) {
    $block = $this->getLayout()->getBlock($name);
    if (!$block) {
        Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('core')->__('Invalid block: %s', $name));
    }
    $this->addText($block->toHtml());
}
```

т.е поднятие добавленных блоков через `getSortedChildren` и процессинг (рендерин) их через `$block->toHtml()`

Answer (score 3):

Изменять можно все блоки в magento.

Информацию про **layout** Вы можете найти [здесь](http://freaksidea.com/php_and_somethings/show-49-magento-konfighuratsiia-ot-a-do-ia-layout-updates) или [здесь](http://www.magentocommerce.com/design_guide/articles/intro-to-layouts)

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас почитаю.

зы: я понимаю что изменять можно всё :) Но меня больше интересовала возможность изменять именно через layout update.

Пойду просвящатся :)

Comment: не нашел я там ответа на свои вопросы :(